# windows 10 - "No Audio Output Device is Installed" after latest update

Tags: windows-10, audio, usb-audio

Windows 10 all of a sudden disabled my audio and all the playback devices disappeared (maybe after windows update). I tried almost everything to fix it (like driver updates, uninstalling drivers etc.,). But I'm unable to fix it.

[image]

I decided to try USB Sound Adapter but still its not discovering any audio devices.

Any idea what's the issue is? I did select `show disabled audio devices` as well.

[image]

In device manager I see that `USB Pnp Device` is visible but no audio and its not showing up in playback devices. I disabled other audio devices just to test.

[image]

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Windows 10 all of a sudden disabled my audio and all the playback
> devices disappeared (maybe after windows update). I tried almost
> everything to fix it (like driver updates, uninstalling drivers
> etc.,). But I'm unable to fix it.

Update BIOS, power drivers and Audio Drivers. Best approach: Get the PC Manufacturer's Driver Update App, run that and update ALL drivers.

Also get their Hardware Diagnostic App to check for hardware issues.

It appears there may be a hardware issue.

Be sure Windows is fully up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/no-audio-output-device-is-installed-after-latest/7284c3da-044b-464e-959e-1eb2d8a97981). The issue was due to windows update. I had to turn on the `mono audio` and the playback devices started showing up.

[image]

[image]